# How to make scrollview scroll separately to its content height in swift

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, height

I have view hierarchy like below in storyboard

[image]

here for **content main** constrains `top = 0, leading = 0, trailing = 0, bottom = 0`

here for **scrollview** constrains `top = 0, leading = 0, trailing = 0, bottom = 0`

here for **View** constrains `top = 0, leading = 0, trailing = 0, bottom = 0`

for **ContentView** constrains `top = 0, leading = 0, trailing = 0`

for **TblReview** constrains `top = 0, leading = 0, trailing = 0, bottom = 20`

for **Productcollectionview** constrains `top = 0, leading = 0, trailing = 0, bottom = 20, height = 400`

and i have Productcollectionview height outlet like below in swift file

**and i don't want collectionview separate scrolling.. i want total view to scroll according to collectionview cells.. so for that i have written below code** but with this code `contentView and tblReview also scrolling upto productioncollectionview height` i need contentView should scroll upto its content height and tblReview should scroll upto its rows

how to make scrolling separately to its height.

please help me to solve this issue

```
  @IBOutlet weak var productCollHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    productCollectionView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: .new, context: nil)
} 
 override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    let collectionView = object as? UICollectionView
    if collectionView == self.productCollectionView{
        if(keyPath == "contentSize"){
            if let newvalue = change?[.newKey]
            {
                let newsize  = newvalue as! CGSize
                self.productCollHeight.constant = newsize.height
            }
        }
    }
    }

@IBAction func aboutCompany(_ sender: UIButton){
self.productCollectionView.isHidden = true
self.tblReview.isHidden = true
self.contentView.isHidden = false
}

@IBAction func review(_ sender: UIButton){

self.productCollectionView.isHidden = true
self.tblReview.isHidden = false
self.contentView.isHidden = true
}

@IBAction func productOfSeller(_ sender: UIButton){
self.productCollectionView.isHidden = false
self.tblReview.isHidden = true
self.contentView.isHidden = true

}
```

and i am hiding and showing tblReview and contentView according to need

**with the above code tblReview and contentView are also scrolling upto productCollectionView height**.. please help me to solve this error

EDIT: `share this seller` is out of scrollview so here **contentView height is not not so long but if i scroll the contentView also scrolling too long like productioncollectionview**

**this is contentView which is scrolling too long like productioncollectionview**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

if your all constraint are proper than just use it like this you don't need to count every time. `UICollectionView` has `intrinsicContentSize` it will count it properly.

```
final class ContentSizedCollectionView: UICollectionView {
    override var contentSize:CGSize {
        didSet {
            invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        layoutIfNeeded()
        return CGSize(width: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric, height: contentSize.height)
    }
}
```

put that code in controller or wherever you wan to put and assign `ContentSizedCollectionView` class to your collectionview.

**NOTE**: you can also use it with `UITableView` after creating for `UITableView`.

Comment: i have edited my post with image in the last to understand..pls do some help